# How to make urls secure on GAE using the django_wsgi builtin

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm running Django on AppEngine (python 2.7 runtime) using their Cloud SQL. I've setup the application as described in Google's Cloud SQL docs [Django Support](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django). Everything is working great, but I want to make some of the urls secure, and I can't find any documentation on how to do that.

Normally you would just add the 'secure: always' to the handler you want secure, but as I'm not specifying the handlers/script for the app (I'm assuming the 'django_wsgi' builtin is doing that) there is no place to add the secure setting.

My app.yaml file is:

```
application: app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true


libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
- deferred: on

handlers:
- url: /media
  static_dir: media
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The django_wsgi builtin is actually just adding the following to app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.django.main.app
  position: tail
```

So you can just replace the builtin-directive with this handler and add the secure-clause to the handler.

Comment: Had to remove the `position: tail` as that isn't supported in the app.yaml, but otherwise worked perfect.